# typeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'tView' of object '[object Object]' in angular when redirect by login Url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, ngrx

I have two angular apps one is website and other one is load when we login.I have an issue when i goes to login component(in second app after login) with JWT Authentications it load splash screen in app.component.ts file  and  faced an error shows in screenshot attached with my question.After that i see splash screen long time instead of redirect to url.Please help me if you can.Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nekbi.png)

```
Package.Json File  
 {
  "name": "metronic-angular",
  "version": "6.0.6",
  "description": "Packages used by Angular",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "echo hello && ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.14",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.10",
    "highlight.js": "^9.15.8",
    "inputmask": "^5.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^8.5.1",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.2.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.2.0",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tinymce": "^5.0.16",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.13",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

```
App.Module

// Angular
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
// Angular in memory
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
// Perfect Scroll bar
import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
// SVG inline
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';
// Env
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
// NGX Permissions
import { NgxPermissionsModule } from 'ngx-permissions';
// NGRX
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreRouterConnectingModule } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
// State
import { metaReducers, reducers } from './core/reducers';
// Copmponents
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// Modules
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from "./views/theme/theme.module";
// Partials
import { PartialsModule } from './views/partials/partials.module';
// Layout Services
import {
    DataTableService,
    FakeApiService,
    KtDialogService,
    LayoutConfigService,
    LayoutRefService,
    MenuAsideService,
    MenuConfigService,
    MenuHorizontalService,
    PageConfigService,
    SplashScreenService,
    SubheaderService
} from './core/_base/layout';
// Auth
import { AuthModule } from './views/pages/auth/auth.module';
import { AuthService } from './core/auth';
// CRUD
import { HttpUtilsService, LayoutUtilsService, TypesUtilsService } from './core/_base/crud';
// Config
import { LayoutConfig } from './core/_config/layout.config';
// Highlight JS
import { HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS, HighlightLanguage } from 'ngx-highlightjs';
import * as typescript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript';
import * as scss from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/scss';
import * as xml from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml';
import * as json from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/json';

// tslint:disable-next-line:class-name
const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
    wheelSpeed: 0.5,
    swipeEasing: true,
    minScrollbarLength: 40,
    maxScrollbarLength: 300,
};

    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers,
        {
            metaReducers,
            //runtimeChecks: {
            //  strictStateImmutability: false,
            //  strictActionImmutability: false,
            //  strictStateSerializability: false,
            //  strictActionSerializability: false,
            //}
        }
    )
export function initializeLayoutConfig(appConfig: LayoutConfigService) {
    // initialize app by loading default demo layout config
    return () => {
        if (appConfig.getConfig() === null) {
            appConfig.loadConfigs(new LayoutConfig().configs);
        }
    };
}

export function hljsLanguages(): HighlightLanguage[] {
    return [
        { name: 'typescript', func: typescript },
        { name: 'scss', func: scss },
        { name: 'xml', func: xml },
        { name: 'json', func: json }
    ];
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        environment.isMockEnabled ? HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(FakeApiService, {
            passThruUnknownUrl: true,
            dataEncapsulation: false
        }) : [],
        NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
        PartialsModule,
        CoreModule,
        OverlayModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ stateKey: 'router' }),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
        AuthModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
        ThemeModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        LayoutConfigService,
        LayoutRefService,
        MenuConfigService,
        PageConfigService,
        KtDialogService,
        DataTableService,
        SplashScreenService,
        {
            provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
            useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
        },
        {
            // layout config initializer
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeLayoutConfig,
            deps: [LayoutConfigService], multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: { languages: hljsLanguages }
        },
        // template services
        SubheaderService,
        MenuHorizontalService,
        MenuAsideService,
        HttpUtilsService,
        TypesUtilsService,
        LayoutUtilsService,
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

```
app.component.ts

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
// Angular
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
// Layout
import { LayoutConfigService, SplashScreenService, TranslationService } from './core/_base/layout';
// language list
import { locale as enLang } from './core/_config/i18n/en';
import { locale as chLang } from './core/_config/i18n/ch';
import { locale as esLang } from './core/_config/i18n/es';
import { locale as jpLang } from './core/_config/i18n/jp';
import { locale as deLang } from './core/_config/i18n/de';
import { locale as frLang } from './core/_config/i18n/fr';

@Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'body[kt-root]',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    // Public properties
    title = 'Metronic';
    loader: boolean;
    private unsubscribe: Subscription[] = []; // Read more: => https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

    /**
     * Component constructor
     *
     * @param translationService: TranslationService
     * @param router: Router
     * @param layoutConfigService: LayoutCongifService
     * @param splashScreenService: SplashScreenService
     */
    constructor(private translationService: TranslationService,
                private router: Router,
                private layoutConfigService: LayoutConfigService,
                private splashScreenService: SplashScreenService) {

        // register translations
        this.translationService.loadTranslations(enLang, chLang, esLang, jpLang, deLang, frLang);
    }

    /**
     * @ Lifecycle sequences => https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
     */

    /**
     * On init
     */
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // enable/disable loader
        this.loader = this.layoutConfigService.getConfig('loader.enabled');
        console.log("LoaderStart");



        const routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            console.log(event);



            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                // hide splash screen
                this.splashScreenService.hide();
                console.log("True");
                // scroll to top on every route change
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);

                // to display back the body content
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.body.classList.add('kt-page--loaded');
                }, 500);
            }
        });
        this.unsubscribe.push(routerSubscription);
    }

    /**
     * On Destroy
     */
    ngOnDestroy() {
        
        /*this.unsubscribe.forEach(sb => sb.unsubscribe());*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade NgRx to v12, it ignores runtime checks for router events.
These events are causing the problem.